# How to set text if your query field is equal to zero

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have textbox i can retrieve all data from database

But how if my stock fieldname is equal to zero"0" on database and it will show to my textbox Stock is "Out of stock" instead of number ZERO "0"

```
 private void txt_searchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {    
String sql=" SELECT * FROM stocktbl WHERE   ID =?";

    try{       
     rs=pst.executeQuery();        
     pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     pst.setString(1,txt_search.getText());
     rs=pst.executeQuery();

    if(rs.next()){
    String add1=rs.getString("ID");
    txt_id.setText(add1);
    String add2=rs.getString("Name");
   txt_name.setText(add2);
   String add3=rs.getString("Stock");
     txt_stock.setText(add3);  
    String add4=rs.getString("Price");
   txt_Price.setText(add4);


  if(add3.equals("0")){
   txt_qty.setEnabled(false);
   txt_qty.setText("Out of stock");
   }

    }


    }catch(Exception e)
    {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }

}
```

Comment: To post code as text, copy and paste in the text area, select all of the code, and hit Ctrl-K. Do that, then explain what your code is supposed to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: OK. Before doing that, use your IDE to auto-format all the code. All IDEs can do that with a single keyboard shortcut. You can't understand the structure of the code is every line starts at a random position.

Comment: thank you sir now i know my mistake posting code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Integer.parseInt() to convert your string to integer and then check if it is equal to zero.

```
String add3 = rs.getString("Stock");
if (Integer.parseInt(add3) == 0){
    txt_stock.setText("Out of Stock");
} else {
    txt_stock.setText(add3);
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help.